# How should I fix when the array of size does not match (coverting C code to python - testing sequence aln file)

Tags: python, jupyter

I am pretty new to python. Trying to learn as possible as I can. Here is my situation where I am trying to convert c code to python. I am having a problem with my size of array should be matched with the "`all_seq_list`". Let say that I have created the seq = `np.array(MAXSEQLEN, dtype = object)` and MAXSEQLEN is 5000 (an integer). All I am trying to do is to save the first line, which is one sequence and save until all the sequences read. Then save that into seq.

I have tried to use different dtype in array to match with all_seq_list, but it's saying that

```
invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLSKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYK'
```

Is there better solution? Again, I am trying to save all sequence data from all_seq_list and save it into seq array.

```
MAXSEQLEN = 5000
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Res/code/input-features/119L-A.aln','r',) as f:
    seq = np.array(MAXSEQLEN, dtype = object)
    all_seq = f.readlines()
    # Calculate the length of all this sequences in Aln.file
    all_seq_list = [i.split('\n', 1)[0] for i in all_seq]
    print(all_seq_list)     # **first print**
    print(all_seq_list[0])  # **second print**
    print(all_seq_list[1])
    nseq = len(all_seq)
    print(all_seq)
    print(nseq)

    for i in range(0, nseq):
        seq1[i] = all_seq_list[i]
```

Again, the output/input looks like following

for first `print` in the script:

> 'MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLSKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYK',
>   'MDEFDMLRVDEGLKLTVYQDHLGYWTVGIGHLLTKIKDKAKAIQILDNLLGRKTNGVITEKEARQIFADDVAKVKRDIKNSAILSPIYDKVSDTRKLGIINMVFQLGLKGAEGFQNSLTLISNAYYTQAGKNMRKSQWYSQTPNRAERVIKVLTSGTLDAYN',......

till the end of the protein sequence.

For second and third `print` in the script:

> MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLSKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYK
>   MDEFDMLRVDEGLKLTVYQDHLGYWTVGIGHLLTKIKDKAKAIQILDNLLGRKTNGVITEKEARQIFADDVAKVKRDIKNSAILSPIYDKVSDTRKLGIINMVFQLGLKGAEGFQNSLTLISNAYYTQAGKNMRKSQWYSQTPNRAERVIKVLTSGTLDAYN

then print for all_seq is 1094 : which represent the number of protein sequences
print for nseq = 163 : which represent the sequence length

Comment: what is the output and input look like? are you trying to get first line of file then save to numpy array?

Comment: Nope like saving every line by line into numpy array

Comment: So..basicly you deleted your previous account, reformatted the question.. didn't read O'Reilly and failed on BioPython... realy!! Learn by improving your question. It was quite funny to get your question the second time   for triage review in less than 24h. Anyway, this time more text and explanation and you finalized the tour. GO and get BioPython installed and start using it. Sneakpeak in the BLAST and BLASTN engin how they did it. Also checkout how they load the weighing tables and enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: I am not supposed to use BioPython. I am really trying at the same time i posted it after 24 hours. The question is more concrete than previous question.

Comment: ..oooh ... you.... its an asignment from school. Just have a look how they did it and then your brightlight starts to shine because you then know how to solve it yourself.

Comment: It's not assignment from school. I just have my own project. I know there is a easy tool that are available for this. But I wanted to finish this with my current code, so that at least I would learn something from it. I did what other people said. Tried to debug and research for what I should do.

Comment: I know that it should be simple to solve this, and I just could not figure out. That's why I asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: Then get yourself a copy of **Python Data Science Handbook** from VanderPlas (O'Reilly). It teaches you exactly how to manipulate arrays. One of the reasons your question was downvoted yesterday is that you were asking for reference material and tutorials. Just look at different questions with np.array goodies. There are many of those questions on SO. The book is gold for life! Also, post the minimal working example because MAXSEQLEN is currently not defined in your script.

Comment: I do not know why are you being so harsh on this. Isn't it obvious that you can see that I have tried, I have tried different dtype things to solve it or search how char type of array can store those sequences. Then I could not figure out, so I post it. I post this because I want to see what expert can comment on this particular problem. I can edit that real quick, but like I defined in the post

Comment: I'm pointing you with the book reference and biopython to the exact information you need to solve it. Via biopython you learn to reverse engineer it for your own purpose and with the book you learn a lot more than reverse engineering or someone coding for you here as answer. This is basic stuff you should be able to handle yourself at first glans. So go get the book and become an `array-master`. Pushed question to 'requires-editing' for shortening the protein sequences to just two or three lines each.

Comment: I will keep it in my mind for that book, and Thanks for pointing out, but I need to get this done by 12/31. So I have limited time to work on this project. I know that I am little experienced python, but I really am trying to do this.Once this thing is figured out. Everything will work out within rest of my code.

Comment: Add also minimalistic protseq from .aln file by using '>' sign and giving it the heading "testdata" or something like it. Use < br > without white spaces to tell the script its a new line. Python 2.7 or 3.x?

Comment: could you send me the link that could help me out? it's python 3.

Comment: what is in the .aln file. Post it so I can copy  and look at it. Post also a complete script... with import xyz... we're lazy...

Comment: It's pretty big. it has 1094 lines and 163 long sequences. but let me post 2 sequences.   MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLSKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYK
MDEFDMLRVDEGLKLTVYQDHLGYWTVGIGHLLTKIKDKAKAIQILDNLLGRKTNGVITEKEARQIFADDVAKVKRDIKNSAILSPIYDKVSDTRKLGIINMVFQLGLKGAEGFQNSLTLISNAYYTQAGKNMRKSQWYSQTPNRAERVIKVLTSGTLDAYN

Comment: that is two sequences

Comment: Well I am not sure what you are asking for, you want to see the content in aln file? or my script?

Comment: That's cutting down towards a working example. I'll get you out there before 31/12 no worries. Hitting bed in a sec. You should add the protseqs into your question with the label "test sequences" for xyz.aln file as explained above. Also paste back in the reference to the c-scritp you posted earlier. Now the reference in question title is lost.

Comment: Okay, I changed the question label. Thanks for your help! I really do appreciated

Comment: the testdata under label and boxed with '>' and use of <br> in your question seperated from your .py-file script.

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand what you want me to do. Is there way that I can directly talk to you?

Comment: nope... but its being implemented as we speak. See the yellow boxes that appeared in your question :-)

Comment: yea I see the yellow box

Comment: if you want to take a look at the aln file. here is the shared google drive link  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GqQPjMJDmgW99X20p7-9JpVyzxqHxJIH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: seq1 is missing its definition... Got the file..will have a look at it tomorrow. I'll update the question lateron.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... lengthly discussion on how to get question on par. Now it is with the bunch of reformatting and implementing testdata in clear visable way.

Running the script will produce the folling error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    ....File "D:\Scripts\XYZ\Python3-1.py", line 15, in 
>       ........print(all_seq_list[1])
>   IndexError: list index out of range

This makes sense because there are two sequences to read from the .aln file. So print(all_seq_list[1]) tries to find something that is not in the list.

You want the following:

```
print(all_seq_list[0][0])
```

This gives the first item (readline 1).

```
print(all_seq_list[0][1])
```

This gives the second item (readline 2).

But its not producing the error:

> invalid literal for long() with base 10:

recycling the alignment seq many times in the .aln file gave me the following error:

> NameError: name 'seq1' is not defined

... awaiting update of py.script. SJ...also include `import numpy as np`, etc... Now really off to bed (this line will be removed once answer is updated. Work in progress).

After one night of good sleep the remaining code was posted. You try several things at once. I've cut them down in separate parts.

When you say:

```
 seq = np.array(MAXSEQLEN, dtype = object)  #1
 print (seq.size, seq.ndim)                 #2
```

You get:

> 1): array([MAXSEQLEN]) -> 5000 
>   2): 1, 0

In 2) it means you have one value and a single dimension in size of your array.
MAXSEQLEN is the value you are going to reuse to test each sequence for maximum positions in the aminoacid string. That in this case includes the empty spaces ('-'). Prior to alignment you probably already checked it visually. Not sure but your implementation tells me you didn't check and the alignment was done by commandline execution.

So.. I assume you want a 2D array.

In: `np.array([['sorting parameters', 'sortparam2', 'sp3', 'spx' ][seq1, seq2, seqn]])`

Out : obviously you print this yourself.

Replace your code:

```
seq = np.array([MAXSEQLEN], dtype = object)
```

with:

```
seq = np.array([MAXSEQLEN, 'sequences'], dtype = object)
```

And then:

```
print (seq[0],'\n\n', seq[1])
```

You will now see that you extended your array by one and thus total size = 2.

Try:

```
...snippet code...
nseq = 2

for i in range(0, nseq):
    print (i)
    seq[i] = all_seq_list[i]
```

You get:

> 60 
>   2 1 
>   5000 
>   
>    sequences
>   0
>   1

Now try:

```
...snippet code...
nseq = 60

for i in range(0, nseq):
    print (i)
    seq[i] = all_seq_list[i]
```

You get:

> IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

.. because your index doesn't go beyond two items.

Try:

```
...snippet code...
seq[1] = 'yet another string of amino acids'  # this overwrites the value at position 1 in the array; not position 0.

nseq = 2

for i in range(0, nseq):
    print (i, seq[i])
    seq[i] = all_seq_list[i]
```

Now you get:

> 60 
>   2 1 
>   5000 
>   
>    sequences
>   0 5000 
>   1 yet another string of amino acids

So... this explanation will help you getting over the codingbump. I'm convinced that you are able to solve it because there are from this point three or more possible solutions to fix it. Tip: create the array after you did load the list0 of aminoacid strings. And thereafter do the maxseqlen or directly after you created the list0 and append each "checked" string to a new list1.

Enjoy the tips to get it fixed and don't forget to buy yourself a copy of that Python Data Science Book I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I post the script

Answer (score 0):

```
#The code 
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
import numpy as np
import math

##Global Variable
MAXSEQLEN = 5000
nseq = 0
rescode ='ARNDCQEGHILKMFPSTWYVXXX'
seq_len = len(seq) - 1
pab = np.zeros((21,21), dtype = float)
aln = np.zeros((seq_len,seq_len), dtype = float)
aacomp = np.zeros((21), dtype = float)
pa = np.zeros((MAXSEQLEN,21), dtype = float)
pav = np.zeros((MAXSEQLEN, 21), dtype = float)
##misum = np.zeros((MAXSEQLEN), dtpye = float)

def annum(ch):
  const_aacvs = [999,0, 3, 4, 3, 6,13, 7, 8, 9, 21, 11, 10, 12, 2, 
21,14,5,1,15,16,21,19, 17, 21, 18, 6]
  return const_aacvs[ord(ch) & 30] if ch.isalphat() else 20

##Taking in the file, then read line/save that into sequence array
## then make aln arrays and calculate the weight '119L-A.aln

with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Res/code/input-features/119L-A.aln','r',) as f:
  seq = np.array(MAXSEQLEN, dtype = object)
  all_seq = f.readlines()
## Calculate the length of all this sequences in Aln.file
  all_seq_list = [i.split('\n', 1)[0] for i in all_seq]
  for this_seq in all_seq:
    nseq = len(all_seq)
  for i in range(0, nseq):
    seq1[i] = all_seq_list[i]
```

I think the problem occurs when I am trying to save the sequence into seq array and the same error occurs! also, when I print print(all_seq_list[1]) it gave me the second sequence.

Comment: sorry seq1 should be just seq